# MySQL: Retrieve different columns from different tables based on third table column values

Tags: sql, mysql

let's say I have a table called table1 that has two columns: tableNames and columnNames and looks like this:

| tableNames--- | columnNames |
| --- | --- |
| table_242432 | colX342X234 |
| table_134 | colX12X3 |
| ... | .... |

So each row represents the name of another table in my database and the name of a specific column within this table. Even though the names are all different, the information within these columns in these different tables is of the same nature and I want to retrieve it as a single column.
I don't know the number of rows in table1 beforehand.
Is there an easy way to do this in mysql or should I use separated queries and then stitch the results together using php?

I tried creating some queries but to no good result.

Comment: for that you must use a procedure with a cursor and dynamic sql and insert the data in a temporary table

Comment: This sounds like a bad design decision and probably denormalisation

Comment: @Stu, the design stems from another software, I just have to work with it.

Comment: Can you not just do `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ', columnNames, ' FROM ', tableNames) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') FROM YourTable` and then run the resulting command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way.

In SQL, the table names and column names (and all other identifiers and expressions) are fixed at the time the query is parsed — i.e. before any rows are read. So there is no way a query can "discover" which tables and columns to read after it begins reading data.

The hard way is to make outer joins to *ALL* your tables, and use conditional expressions to identify the column based on the data values. In the following example, the quoted strings must be hard-coded in your expression, and the identifiers (without quotes) will return the value of the corresponding column.

```
SELECT
  CASE table1.tableNames 
  WHEN 'table_242432' THEN
    CASE table1.columnNames
    WHEN 'colX342X234' THEN table_242432.colX342X234
    END
  WHEN 'table_134' THEN
    CASE table1.columnNames
    WHEN 'colX12X3' THEN table_134.colX12X3
    END
  END AS `value`
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_242432 ON ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_134 ON ...
```

I'm supposing there is some join condition between `table1` and each of the related tables, but you haven't described it.

This still requires you to know every possible table and column up front,  before you can write that query. If you have more than a few possibilities, the expression will be ridiculously large.

Also you have a Cartesian product between each of the subordinate tables, so the number of rows returned are multiplied together in dramatic ways.

This is a case where it's really more appropriate to implement as multiple queries.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. To be honest, I expected something like that. I will mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: as you wrote that you don't know the content of the table this will be lots of work, so see my comment and try a dynamic approach

Comment: I really don't like MySQL procedures and using cursors in procedures. I'd rather write the code in nearly any other client language. You are welcome to post an answer showing your method.